# Bokeh: Update figure multiple times in a single Python callback

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to update a figure multiple times within a single Python callback. As a simple example, say after clicking on a button, I want to change the coordinates of a line 10 times, each time displaying the changed line for a short time. You can call that an animation if you like.

In the Bokeh documentation, I only found [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#updating-from-unlocked-callbacks).

Here is a non-working example, illustrating what I want:

```
from time import sleep
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Button
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.events import ButtonClick

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 0]))
doc = curdoc()


def button_pushed():
    for i in range(10):
        source.data = dict(x=[0, 1], y=[i, i])
        sleep(0.5)


p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300)
p.line(source=source, x='x', y='y')

button = Button(label='Draw')
button.on_event(ButtonClick, lambda: button_pushed())

doc.add_root(column(button, p))
```

With the above code as a Bokeh app, the line is updated only once after the callback is executed completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `asyncio` to do this. Do your calculation in `loop()` and then use
`doc.add_next_tick_callback()` to update the data source.

```
from functools import partial
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Button
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.events import ButtonClick
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import asyncio

def view(doc):
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 0]))

    def update_source(new_data):
        source.data = new_data

    async def loop():
        for i in range(10):
            doc.add_next_tick_callback(partial(update_source, dict(x=[0, 1], y=[i, i**2])))
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    def button_pushed():
        IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(loop)

    p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300)
    p.line(source=source, x='x', y='y')

    button = Button(label='Draw')
    button.on_event(ButtonClick, button_pushed)

    doc.add_root(column(button, p))

show(view)
```

Comment: To add some additional context: Python/JS state is synchronized when a callback ends, so multiple updates to the same property inside a callback are invisible to BokehJS